# Detect which IP use in ASP.NET site with multiple bindings

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET application setup in IIS 7 that uses two HTTP bindings on port 80, each with a different IP address.

This web server is behind a load balancer which could forward traffic on to the web server via either of the IP addresses (depending upon circumstances which aren't important).

Is there away for my application to detect which IP was being used by the load balancer - is it simply available via the REMOTE_ADDR server variable in the Request (assuming the load balancer overrides this)?

I think its an F5 load balancer is that helps!

Comment: What have you tried?  Specifically have you actually inspected the REMOTE_ADDR variable to determine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the answer was to use the LOCAL_ADDR variable as this represented the the server address on which the request came in - the load balancer.

[Great info on server variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will display all of the relevant data: (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables(v=vs.90).aspx )

```
int loop1, loop2;
NameValueCollection coll;

// Load ServerVariable collection into NameValueCollection object.
coll=Request.ServerVariables; 
// Get names of all keys into a string array. 
String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys; 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
   Response.Write("Key: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
   String[] arr2=coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
   for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) {
      Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
   }
}
```

Within this you'll find REMOTE_ADDR which references the client, and SERVER_PORT which references the IIS host.